# Product Notation Problem

Tags: notation, products

Can Someone help me with these on product Notation?

> The notation $ \prod _ { i = 1 } ^ N p _ i $ denotes the product with $ N $ factors:
> $$ \prod _ { i = 1 } ^ N p _ i = p _ 1 p _ 2 \dots p _ N \text . $$
> Compute the following products.
>
> 1. $ \prod _ { i = 1 } ^ M \frac 1 \theta $
> 2. $ \prod _ { k = 1 } ^ K \frac k { k + 1 } $
> 3. $ \ln \left( \prod _ { k = 1 } ^ K e ^ k \right) $

Comment: What's your question? Did you manage to solve, for example, the first one?

Comment: Are M and K given? Is theta a number? Maybe you are just asked to write it down like in the definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just give you hints. The first is a product of $M$ apparently equal factors. The second is a telescoping product. For the third, use $\ln\prod_ke^{f(k)}=\sum_k\ln e^{f(k)}=\sum_kf(k)$.